# "try-finally" block vs. "using" block when disposing of SymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

According to the [msdn docs for System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx)

> Note that when using derived classes, it is not enough, from a security perspective, to simply force a garbage collection after you have finished using the object. You must explicitly call the Clear method on the object to zero out any sensitive data within the object before it is released. Note that garbage collection does not zero out the contents of collected objects but simply marks the memory as available for reallocation. Thus the data contained within a garbage collected object may still be present in the memory heap in unallocated memory. In the case of cryptographic objects, this data could contain sensitive information such as key data or a block of plain text.
>
> All cryptographic classes in the .NET Framework that hold sensitive data implement a Clear method. When called, the Clear method overwrites all sensitive data within the object with zeros and then releases the object so that it can be safely garbage collected. When the object has been zeroed and released, you should then call the Dispose method with the disposing parameter set to True to dispose of all managed and unmanaged resources associated with the object.

What I'm getting from this is that I have to use a try-finally block to dispose of my algorithm, like so:

```
SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create()
try 
{
     //stuff
}
finally
{
    symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();
    symmetricAlgorithm.Dispose(true)
}
```

I wouldn't be able to use the more concise `using` block

```
using (var symmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

because it won't clear the memory. It will only mark it for collection. Is that correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Btw, the end of the using statement won't mark the object for colleciton. It should release any unmanaged resource held by the object. Collection will happen once there are no more references to the object (including the stack or registers).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how Clear method is implemented (from Reflector):

```
public void Clear()
{
    ((IDisposable) this).Dispose();
}
```

So you can use `using` block.

Comment: That's what I expected. Would have been strange to have both `Clear` and `Dispose` with subtly different semantics. Typically those functions are equivalent(for example `Close` and `Dispose` on streams). Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 17):

> [calling Dispose] will only mark it for collection. Is that correct?

No it is not correct. You have a misunderstanding of what "Dispose" does. This is a very common misunderstanding.

Let me be super clear on this point: **"Dispose" in of itself has absolutely nothing to do with garbage collection.** There's nothing special about "Dispose" that you couldn't do in any other method with any other name. Many people believe the following myths:

- Calling a method called Dispose on an object that implements an interface called IDisposable "marks" the object for collection.
- The garbage collector calls IDisposable.Dispose when an object is collected.

Neither of those myths are true.

The facts are:

- Calling "Dispose" when you are done with an object is a *convention* that is intended to ensure that *non-managed resources* are cleaned up *before* the garbage collector gets around to cleaning up the *managed memory resources* associated with an object.
- The garbage collector decides when an object is to be collected solely based on whether any reference to the object is reachable through a known-to-be-alive object. Calling "Dispose", or any other method, does nothing to make an object unreachable.
- The garbage collector will (sometimes) call a "finalizer" (aka "destructor") on an object shortly before it is collected. As a convention, the author of an object typically chooses to have the finalization of an object be identical to its disposal. But again, this is just a convention.
- As a convention, an object that has just been disposed should tell the garbage collector that the GC can safely skip finalization of this object when it eventually becomes unreachable.

"Dispose" is just a method. If that method happens to tell the GC a bunch of stuff, like "by the way, someone has already taken care of finalizing this object", the method is free to do so. There is no magic inherent in "Dispose".  You could write up your own method "MyDispose" and your own interface "IMyDisposable" that did the same thing; the GC neither knows nor cares what conventions you have chosen to organize your code so that it releases unmanaged resources early.

Comment: `There is no magic inherent in Dispose` - with regards to finalization and garbage collection, yes. But it may be worth pointing out that `IDisposable` is "special" in that it's the interface required to support a type as the target of a `using(...) { }` statement ... which may contribute to why it may be thought by some that it has some special treatment with regards to garbage collection.

Comment: @LBushkin: I agree, this does contribute. A lot of people do not realize that "using" is little more than a C# syntactic sugar for a "finally" block with a call to Dispose in it.

Comment: Eric, are you trying to point to the fact that the local variable declared in resource acquisition are read only and that the using statement can correctly handle value types/reference types/ 'dynamic' type? Is there anything 'more' about the using statement?

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Yep, that's pretty much it. It's not "just" a syntactic sugar as there are some semantic effects there. The thing to realize though is that all of it is just compiler magic; there's no "special" interaction with the runtime.

Comment: I got these details from the (excellent) C# spec and it's very clear that   it's all compiler magic and it has nothing to do with runtime. I was just trying to make sure that I wasn't missing anything. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: After this excellent write up, one keeps wondering if Clear() should still be called. i can see in the post of Andrew Bezzub that Dispose() is called from Clear(), but not the other way around. So using "using" does not seem to matter too much. Am I correct or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: If Clear only calls Dispose in its body, then calling Dispose using 'using' statement should be enough.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, if Documentation suggests you call the 'Clear' method, I think it's a good idea to call it. You never know if implementation of 'Clear' will change in future. Also, it is more readable to future developers who have to maintain the code.

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Though I totally agree with your point in general -- write code so that it is (1) clear and (2) does exactly what is recommended in the documentation -- the people who supply the crypto types are *extremely* security conscious and are not going to go making changes that cause commonly-used patterns to suddenly start breaking silently. It is reasonable to expect that Dispose and Clear will be synonyms forever.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough discussion of IDisposable and the Dispose method. I'm sure I've read it all before and just forgotten it. Hopefully this will do the trick for memorizing it, and it'll be one less person to frustrate you with a fundamental misunderstanding of garbage collection.

Comment: But an official MSDN documentation on SymmetricAlgorithm.Clear Method () says,
"When called, the Clear method overwrites all sensitive data within the object with zeros and then releases the object so that it can be safely garbage collected. When the object has been zeroed and released, you should then call the Dispose method with the disposing parameter set to True "

 So, is MSDN documentation wrong and SymmetricAlgorithm.Clear() does not "overwrite all sensitive data within the object with zeros "?

 Is it also wrong and there is no need to call Dispose(true)  after calling Clear() ?

Comment: @vkelman: The question was "does the dispose method mark the object as collectable?" and the answer to that question is "no". You then ask "*is MSDN documentation wrong?*" No. The documentation is not wrong; Clear clears the object.  You then ask "*is it also wrong and there is no need to call Dispose(true) after calling Clear()*".  **NO THE DOCUMENTATION IS NOT WRONG**.  If you are extending this base class then you are **required** to call `Dispose(true)` after the object is cleared.  **The documentation you are referring to is for extenders**.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I got confused because in a post above Andrew Bezzub said that Reflector shows that Clear() just calls public Dispose() and doesn't do anything else.
I'm trying to confirm an exact behavior of SymmetricAlgorithm.Clear()